# how to implement a java class so that it holds constants for other classes in other files

Tags: java, constants

What is the best way to implement a system to establish program-wide constants? I have a program that spans several files and I want to have a class that stores constants so that they are available for all the other files.
I tried something like this:

in `Constants.java`

```
public final class Constants{
    private Constants(){}
    public static final String EX = "mas";
}
```

and in `test.java`

```
import Constants.*;
public class test{
    public static void main( String[]args){
            System.out.println( EX );
    }
}
```

but I get the following error

```
test.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
import static Constants.*;
              ^
  symbol: class Constants
```

`Constants.java` and `test.java` are in the same dir.

Comment: Is your `Constants` class in the default package?

Comment: no, how can i import the Constants class then?

Comment: There are really two questions here...why is the solution you implemented not working, and what is the best way to do the type of thing you want to do.

Comment: the one question what is the best way to do the type of thing i want to do, i just wanted to show an attempt at solving the question. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not import from the default package. See [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5)

Put the class in a package.

Answer (score 1):

You can't import classes without a package (also called the default package)

Answer (score 0):

If these two classes are in the same package, you do not need to import.

1. Remove the import statement for Constants class
2. In your test class, use the following line: Constants.EX to get the value of EX.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to preface your reference to `Constants` in the import with the full package name.

For example, if `Constants` and `test` are in the package "com.mystuff", you'll need to import as follows:

```
import static com.mystuff.Constants.*;
```

Alternatively, since your classes are in the same package you don't really need the import at all - just qualify `EX` with the `Constants` class, e.g. `Constants.EX` instead of just `EX`.

Answer (score 0):

Any public static final variable will be accessible anywhere without creating an instance of an object.  In your case you can access the EX variable with:

```
 Constants.EX;
```

In general with good object-oriented design the constants which you include in a class should be specific to that object type.  For example if you have a Window object its constant might be "aspectRatio" or "height" but it would be inappropriate to have "nameOfUser" in a Window class as a constant.  So sometimes making a "universal" Constants class will inherently make you lose sight of which variables truly belong in different classes when following object-oriented ideals.